# Showing if $f + f'' = 0$ and if $f(0)=a$ and $f'(0)=b$, then $f(x) = b \sin x + a \cos x$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I'm reading Spivak's Calculus, 4th edition Chapter 15. On page 313, there is a proof I'm not quite understanding. I will quote:

> If $f$ has a second derivative everywhere and $f + f'' = 0$, $f(0)=a$, $f'(0)=b$, then $f = b \cdot \sin + a \cdot \cos$

First, I'd like ask how I'm supposed to interpret the equals sign here. Clearly it means the function equals $b \cdot \sin + a \cdot \cos$, which I understand and am convinced (by the proof that follows), **but does it also mean that this is the unique and only form it can take on?**

If the answer is yes, then I'm confused about why the proof adequately shows that this is the ***unique*** form it can take on. I will quote the proof in the book:

> Let $g(x) = f(x) - b \sin x - a \cos x$.
>
> Then $g'(x) = f'(x) - b \cos x + a \sin x$
>
> $g''(x) = f''(x) + b \sin x + a \cos x$
>
> Consequently,
>   $g'' + g = 0$
>   $g(0)=0$
>   $g'(0)=0$
>
> which shows that $0=g(x)=f(x) - b\sin x - a\cos x$ for all $x$

Side note: He uses a Lemma, that if $f'''+f = 0$ and $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$, then $f=0$ to derive the last step in the proof above.

**Question:** How do we know there's not a more general solution to this differential equation? In other words, how do we know that $f(x)$ can't equal $b \sin x - a \cos x + \text{<Insert a function that is neither $\sin$ or $\cos$ such that the conditions required hold>}$?
After all, he started the proof by letting $g(x)$ equal to $f(x) - b\sin x - a\cos x$.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is essentially what he has done.

Suppose $f(x)=b \sin x + a \cos x + g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is your function to be inserted.

Then $f'(x)=b \cos x - a \sin x + g'(x)$

and $f''(x)=-b \sin x - a \cos x + g''(x)$

So $f''(x)+f(x)=-b \sin x - a \cos x + g''(x)+b \sin x + a \cos x + g(x)$

or $f''(x)+f(x)=g''(x)+ g(x)$

We know that $f(x)$ obeys $f''(x)+f(x)=0$, so $0=g''(x)+ g(x)$

So far, no problem. But then we consider $f(0)=b \sin 0 + a \cos 0 + g(0)$

Since $f(0)=a$, we have $a=0+a+g(0) \Rightarrow g(0)=0$

Consider also $f'(0)=b \cos 0 - a \sin 0 + g'(0)$

Since $f'(0)=b$, we have $b=b-0+g'(0) \Rightarrow g'(0)=0$

He then uses his Lemma to prove that $g(x)=0$ for all values of $x$.

Thus your suggested alternative function is shown to be $b \sin x + a \cos x + 0$: no different to the suggested form at all!

Answer (score 0):

If 
$$
g''+g=0, \quad\text{and}\quad g(0)=g'(0)=0,
$$
then
$$
0=g'g''+gg'=\frac{1}{2}\big(g^2+(g')^2\big)',
$$
and thus
$$
0=\int_0^x(g'g''+gg')\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\big(g^2(x)+(g')^2(x)\big)-
\frac{1}{2}\big(g^2(0)+(g')^2(0)\big)
\\=\frac{1}{2}\big(g^2(x)+(g')^2(x)\big)
$$
and hence $g(x)=g'(x)=0$, for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

How do we know there's not a more general solution to this differential equation?  Because that is precisely what you showed! You had no restriction on $f$ in the beginning other than the IVP. Then you proved that $f$ is none other than that trig function. So, if $h$ is another hypothetical solution then again you show that it too equals the sine and cosine combination above.

Also, it is a universal fact that solutions to regular enough then solutions are unique.

Answer (score 0):

$$f''+f=0$$
Multipy by $ \mu(x)=\sin x$:
$$f''\sin x+f \sin x=0$$
$$f''\sin x \color{red}{+f' \cos x -f' \cos x}+f \sin x=0$$
$$(f' \sin x)' -(f\cos x)'=0$$
After integration:
$$f' \sin x -f\cos x=c_1$$
$$\left (\dfrac f {\sin x}\right )'= \dfrac {c_1}{\sin^2 x}$$
$$\left (\dfrac f {\sin x}\right )=-{c_1}{\cot x}+c_2$$
Therefore:
$$f(x)={c_1}{\cos x}+c_2 \sin x$$
Apply initial conditions.
$$f(0)=0 \implies c_1=a, f'(0)=b \implies c_2=b$$
$$f(x)=a{\cos x}+b \sin x$$